# What does '%!in%' <- function(x,y)!('%in%'(x,y)) mean?

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to understand this:

```
'%!in%' <- function(x,y)!('%in%'(x,y))
```

Is  `'%!in%'`  just the name of the function? What are the uses/benefits of giving a function a name like this?

What role does `!('%in%'(x,y))` play in the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of naming a function like `%…%` is that it can be used as an [infix operator](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html):

```
4 %in% (1 : 10)
# TRUE

4 %!in% (1 : 10)
# FALSE
```

Since `%…%` isn’t a valid name, it needs to be [backtick-quoted](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html) (with `` `…` ``) when used as a name (e.g. when defining it or when using it as a regular function):

```
# Definition:
`%!in%` = function (x, y) ! x %in% y

# Using function call syntax
`%in%`(4, 1 : 10)

# Passing it to a different function
lapply(c(2, 4, 20), `%in%`, 1 : 10)
```

For historical reasons/backwards compatibility, R also allows you to use regular quotes (`'…'` or `"…"`) instead of backticks in specific situations. However, this usage is confusing and *not recommended!*